# How can I rearrange an array in MATLAB by a specific rule?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose that I have this array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

The output should be something like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,1,3,4,5
3,1,2,4,5
4,1,2,3,5
5,1,2,3,4
```

how Can I do this? This function should be valid for different lengths of `a`.

Comment: is `perms` what you are looking for? https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html Or is the rule that you want to keep the original order but want to have each element once at the first position?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger I don't think so. The results are different. Above output is based on a specific rule (consider first column of above output).

Comment: Ah, i thought that were just some random examples. Thx for the clarification.

Comment: If you need to do this for the vector of a different lengths, You show know it analytic rule. Can you clarify a bit how you create this matrix? Or for example how to create the same matrix for a 1x4 vector or 1x6?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I think the below answers covered my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using combinatory:

```
b = [a.' flipud(nchoosek(a,numel(a)-1))];
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution can be:

```
primarySet = 1:5;
result = zeros(length(primarySet));
for i = 1: length(primarySet)
    temp = primarySet;
    temp(i) = [];
    result(i,:) = [primarySet(i) temp];
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
a = [10 20 30 40 50];
ind = 1:numel(a);
result = a(abs(sort(bsxfun(@times, ind, 1-2*eye(numel(ind))),2)));
```

gives

```
result =
    10    20    30    40    50
    20    10    30    40    50
    30    10    20    40    50
    40    10    20    30    50
    50    10    20    30    40
```

Answer (score 2):

And another way:

```
n = numel(a)-1;
b = [a(:) flipud(reshape(ndgrid(a,1:n).',[],n))];
```

---

```
b =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     1     3     4     5
     3     1     2     4     5
     4     1     2     3     5
     5     1     2     3     4
```